# Is it possible to find an asymptotic distribution for the LRT without the ML estimators being consistent?

Tags: st.statistics

I'm reading a [comment](http://econ.ucsb.edu/~doug/researchpapers/Testing%20for%20Regime%20Switching%20A%20Comment.pdf)(last page) to a paper, and the author states that sometimes, even though the estimators (found by ML or maximum quasilikelihood) may not be consistent, the test may be consistent. How and when does this happen? Do you know of some bibliography?

I've tried MathSE, and CV, but none managed to answer my question. At CV they only gave me an example of when we have a ML estimator which is inconsistent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your test compares two inconsistent estimators on two samples you can still have a consistent test. 
As an example you can think about a stupid mean estimator who shift the estimates by 1. This estimator is inconsistant, nevertheless if you can use it to build a consistent mean comparaison test.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the authors are discussing different things (QMLE vs. QLR) when discussing consistent estimator vs. consistent test. The quasi-likelihood of the QLR is discussed on page 1 of the paper. Also:

[A consistent test is one for which the power of the test for a fixed untrue hypothesis increases to one as the number of data items increases.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_%28statistics%29#Tests)